# Aggregate result not working in soql query

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, aggregate, aggregateresult

im new to visualforce and i have this problem:
I have a sObject with customField1__c, customField2__c, customField3__c.

In my main page (with a standard controller and an extension) i want to display a table in wich i want to see all the customField1__c, customField2__c, customField3__c that are related to my customField1__c.

I'm trying to use a aggregateResult because otherwise i have a lot of duplicates in customField__1, but i have this error:

> "Invalid field customField__c for SObject AggregateResult Error is in
> expression '{!myQuery.customField1}' in component apex:outputText in
> page myQuery"

here is my main page:

```
    <table>
        <tr> <th> My table title </th> </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <b> Field1 </b> </td>
            <td> <b> Fiel2 </b> </td>
            <td> <b> Field3 </b> </td>
        </tr>

        <apex:repeat value="{!myQuery}" var="myQuery">
            <tr>
                <td>  <apex:outputText value="{!myQuery.CustomField1__c}"/> </td>
                <td> <apex:outputText value="{!myQuery.CustomField2__c}"/> </td>
                <td> <apex:outputText value="{!myQuery.CustomField3__c}"/> </td>
            </tr>
        </apex:repeat>
    </table>
```

Then I have my page Extension:

```
public with sharing class MyPageExtension {

    public List<AggregateResult> indicatorNotes{get;set;}

    public MyPageExtension(ApexPages.StandardController ctrl) {   

        myQuery=[ SELECT customField1__c, customField2__c, customField3__c
        FROM customObject__c
               GROUP BY customField1__c, customField2__c, customField3__c
        ];
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`AggregateResult` objects are treated like `sObject` objects; you can't access any of the fields directly with the dot-notation, but instead you need to use the [dynamic notation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf.htm).

```
<td>  <apex:outputText value="{!myQuery['CustomField1__c']}"/> </td>
```

Also, you shouldn't name the `var` the same as the `value`; this can cause the compiler to also not do the right thing.